# Глобальные переменные в Android

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня очень мало опыта в разработке на Android. Подскажите, как **mToken** сделать глобальной, чтобы устанавливать ее в других местах? ...в данном примере, где  ошибка

```
private MenuItem setupMenu(Menu menu) {
    // title list
    String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_title_list);

    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MainActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            String mToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
        }
    });

    String[] urls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_url_list+"?"+mToken );

    // icon list
    TypedArray iconTypedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.navigation_icon_list);
    Integer[] icons = new Integer[iconTypedArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < iconTypedArray.length(); i++) {
        icons[i] = iconTypedArray.getResourceId(i, -1);
    }
    iconTypedArray.recycle();

    // clear menu
    menu.clear();

    // add menu items
    Menu parent = menu;
    MenuItem firstItem = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        if (urls[i].equals("")) {
            // category
            parent = menu.addSubMenu(Menu.NONE, i, i, titles[i]);
        } else {
            // item
            MenuItem item = parent.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, titles[i]);
            if (icons[i] != -1) item.setIcon(icons[i]);
            if (firstItem == null) firstItem = item;
        }
    }

    return firstItem;
}
```

Comment: Не уверен, что даю правильный совет, но я в таком случае использовал класс. Создал класс что-то навроде GlobalVar и в нем публичные переменные. Видно отовсюду.

Comment: А не легче в SharedPreference сохранить?

Comment: Класс проще, мне кажется. И быстрее. SharedPreference сильно избыточны для такой задачи, и они, если память не изменяет, хранят значения в файле, это может сказаться на быстродействии. А сделать класс и добавлять к нему при необходимости статические переменные -  проще не придумаешь. И потом из любого места программы пишешь GolbalVar.variable1 = 347 - что может быть проще?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91528/discussion-on-question-by------android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обьявите переменную mToken возле переменой titles, тогда она будет видна в любом месте этой функции.